# Is there a way to configurate a SSL certificate in Azure Kubernetes Service using WebFlux without use a Java keyStore?

Tags: java, ssl, jks

I have a microservice deploy in AKS plataform and this microservice has to connect an external API that uses a SSL certificates. My doubt if there's a way to configurates the SSL certificate without use a java Keystore, my project is develop in Java language using Spring boot with WebFlux.
I found a example that how can use a jks file and Webflux but not working.

I uses the next code to generates a SslContext:

```
public  SslContext getSslContext(){
 SslContext sslContext;  
 try {  
   KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
   try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my- 
   truststore.jks")) 
  {
     ks.load(is, "truststore-password".toCharArray());
  }
  X509Certificate[] trusted = 
  Collections.list(ks.aliases()).stream().map(alias -> {
     try {
         return (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
     } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
  }).toArray(X509Certificate[]::new);
  sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(trusted).build();
 } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }
}
```

And I uses the next to generate a WebClient:

```
public  WebClient getSslWebClient (){

    try {

        sslContext = getSslContext();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SslContext finalSslContext = sslContext;
    TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> 
                          sslContextSpec.sslContext(finalSslContext));
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.from(tcpClient);
    ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new 
                                      ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);   
    return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(httpConnector).build();
}
```

I appreciate your support in advance.
Regards.

Comment: maybe you can save your certificate in secret and use that secret in your code. secret will be storing certificate and you can use secret as environment variables.

Comment: But I have a .cer file,and from what I have read, I need to register that certificate within the microservice keyStore and generate a key type file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after days of research, I found a way to use a certificate without using the Java KeyStore (JKS). For this, I need the certificate in PEM format, then copy this certificate as a property in the parameter file and then invoke it directly:

```
public class SslConfig {

@Value("${ocp.http-client.certificate}")
private  String certificate;

private final static String certificateType = "X.509";
private final static String alias = "root";

private static SslContext sslContext;

public  WebClient getSslWebClient (){

    try {

        sslContext = getSslContext();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SslContext finalSslContext = sslContext;
    TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(finalSslContext));
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.from(tcpClient);
    ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

    return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(httpConnector).build();
}

//Se configura el contexto sobre el cual se trabajara la comunicacion SSL
public  SslContext getSslContext(){

    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate.getBytes());
        final KeyStore keyStore = readKeyStore(is);

        X509Certificate[] trusted = Collections.list(keyStore.aliases()).stream().map(alias -> {
            try {
                return (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException(e);

            }
        }).toArray(X509Certificate[]::new);
        sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(trusted).build();
    }catch (GeneralSecurityException | SSLException e ){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sslContext;
}

private static KeyStore readKeyStore(InputStream is) throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(null, null);
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance(certificateType);
    Certificate cert = null;
    while (is.available() > 0) {
        cert = cf.generateCertificate(is);
    }
    ks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
    return ks;
}
}
```

After this, I can make a request and get the response what I need.